# Как ограничить доступ пользователя к записи?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Я новичок в Laravel, естьследующая задача:
При создании записи в блоге, администратор может выбирать круг пользователей, которые могут подробно просматривать данную запись (попадать на внутреннюю страницу), остальные пользователи, после авторизации, могут видеть все записи, но открывать запись, к которой у них нет доступа - нельзя.

Я создал связующую таблицу user_records

```
=====================
  user_records_id
  record_id
  user_id
```

У меня получилось сделать выборку из связующей таблицы, но тогда каждый пользователь видит только доступные ему записи, а необходимо, чтобы он мог видеть все, но открывать только те, на которые у него есть права.
Помогите пожалуйста, сижу уже битый час, никак решение не приходит...

Comment: Ну так а в чём проблема? У Вас 2 разных метода и 2 разных запроса в них. Первй метод берёт все новости без подробностей (не знаю, как у Вас сделано, но допустим, берёт short_story, дату создания и автора). Второй метод берёт конкретную новость, где проверяется уже доступность прочтения и, соответственно, всё выбирается.

Comment: Проблема в том, что action отдающий вью - один.

Comment: Ну так сделайте, чтобы был не один?

Comment: Или опишите тогда проблему целиком...

Comment: Почитайте про гейты в ларе. Сделайте гейт и повешайте его на роут редактирования

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регистрируем гейт в провайдере:

```
Gate::define('edit-record', static function (User $user, Record $record) {
    return $user->id === $record->user->id;
});
```

Добавляем мидлвары к роуту

```
Route::put('/records/{record}', [RecordController::class, 'update'])->middleware('can:edit-record');
Route::get('/records/{record}', [RecordController::class, 'edit'])->middleware('can:edit-record');
```

Или вызываем в контроллере

```
public function update(Request $request, Record $record)
{
    if (! Gate::allows('edit-record', $record)) {
        abort(403);
    }
    // Обновляем запись
}
```

Подробней в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#gates)